# read the contents of the input file into a dictionary keyed by id variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a sampleLabs1.txt file like this (it has so many records so I just list 5 rows):

visitid  cdate  ctime   pqno    test    result  unit    range

OMHioJh8XEeq7152 6/15/2007 06:00 1181913408344759 CREAT 0.8 mg/dL 0.5-1.4
OMHioJh8XEeq7152 6/14/2007 07:10 1181827489130119 CREAT 0.8 mg/dL 0.5-1.4
OMHioJh8XEeq7152 6/11/2007 14:21 1181592540465036 CREAT 2.9 mg/dL 0.5-1.4
t2v0TjgroLTI6118 4/28/2006 14:18 1146257767528282 CREAT 8.7 mg/dL 0.5-1.4
t2v0TjgroLTI6118 5/1/2006  04:00 1146487572667772 CREAT 8.0 mg/dL 0.5-1.4

I want to read the contents of the input file into a dictionary keyed by "visitid", that is, I want something like:

{OMHioJh8XEeq7152: 6/15/2007, 06:00, 1181913408344759, CREAT, 0.8, mg/dL, 0.5-1.4,
 OMHioJh8XEeq7152: 6/14/2007, 07:10, 1181827489130119, CREAT, 0.8, mg/dL, 0.5-1.4,
 OMHioJh8XEeq7152: 6/11/2007, 14:21, 1181592540465036, CREAT, 2.9, mg/dL, 0.5-1.4,
 t2v0TjgroLTI6118: 4/28/2006, 14:18, 1146257767528282, CREAT, 8.7, mg/dL, 0.5-1.4,
 t2v0TjgroLTI6118: 5/1/2006,  04:00, 1146487572667772, CREAT, 8.0, mg/dL, 0.5-1.4}

I write the following program:

```
import os
newdict = {}
with open(os.path.join("..","c:\work\python programming","sampleLabs1.txt"),"rU") as f:
    for line in f:
        splitLine = line.split()
        newdict[(splitLine[0])] = ",".join(splitLine[1:])
newdict
```

However, it did give me a dictionary, but it seems that it overwrite the previous record for each key,"visitid", and only 1 unique key ("visitid") is kept. That is, I got something like this:

{OMHioJh8XEeq7152: 6/15/2007, 06:00, 1181913408344759, CREAT, 0.8, mg/dL, 0.5-1.4,
 t2v0TjgroLTI6118: 5/1/2006,  04:00, 1146487572667772, CREAT, 8.0, mg/dL, 0.5-1.4}

But I would like to keep all the records that each "visitid" specifies, something like:

{OMHioJh8XEeq7152: 6/15/2007, 06:00, 1181913408344759, CREAT, 0.8, mg/dL, 0.5-1.4,
 OMHioJh8XEeq7152: 6/14/2007, 07:10, 1181827489130119, CREAT, 0.8, mg/dL, 0.5-1.4,
 OMHioJh8XEeq7152: 6/11/2007, 14:21, 1181592540465036, CREAT, 2.9, mg/dL, 0.5-1.4,
 t2v0TjgroLTI6118: 4/28/2006, 14:18, 1146257767528282, CREAT, 8.7, mg/dL, 0.5-1.4,
 t2v0TjgroLTI6118: 5/1/2006,  04:00, 1146487572667772, CREAT, 8.0, mg/dL, 0.5-1.4}

I will appreciate your help, can anyone help me to fix my code? Thank you for everyone's help.

Comment: your keys (`splitLine[0]`) have duplicates. `dict`s have unique keys

Comment: I would like to keep all the duplicate keys, not only unique key, how do I modify my code? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict, namedtuple
import os

WORKDIR = "c:\work\python programming"

Datum = namedtuple('Datum', ['visitid', 'cdate', 'ctime', 'pqno', 'test', 'result', 'unit', 'range'])

def load_data(fname):
    fname = os.path.join(WORKDIR, fname)
    with open(fname, 'rU') as inf:
        data = (Datum(*(line.split())) for line in inf)
        newdict = defaultdict(list)
        for d in data:
            newdict[d.visitid].append(d)
    return newdict

def main():
    data = load_data('sampleLabs1.txt')
    # now do something with it

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I try to run your code, however, it gives me error message for this piece of code, can you please explain what it suppose to do?                                    def main():
    data = load_data('sampleLabs1.txt')
    # now do something with it

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()

Comment: @neymar: what is the error message? It works as-is for me (Win7 x64, Python 2.7.6)

Comment: Hello. I tried to copy your code into my ipython notebook, and it gives me the error message:                                         TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 9 arguments (2 given)                 Thank you

Comment: @neymar: my bad, should now work (unpacked list of arguments to Datum constructor)

Comment: Hi Hugh, now it gives me this message TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 9 arguments (7 given). I have no idea why it happens. Thank you very much. I know it really took you some time...

Comment: @neymar: at a guess, your text file contains a line such that len(line.split()) == 6 rather than the expected 8 (+ the implicit self argument makes 9). You can either pad such a line out with blanks, or skip it, or convert Datum to a class with argument defaults such that a full 8 arguments are not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to treat this as a database table, if your plan is to analyze all entries under a visitid, or compare averages between visitids, etc etc. The `pandas` package is good for this:

```
import pandas
nd = pandas.read_csv('sampleLabs1.txt',sep=' ')
unique(nd['visitid'])  # all visitid values
nd[nd['visitid'] == 'OMHioJh8XEeq7152']['cdate'] # all cdates for a given visitid
```

To use a dictionary, you need to make the value for each visitid a tuple of some kind -- as in Hugh Bothwell's example.